# Semi log scale Regression line

Tags: r

I've got some coordinates: x and y.
I use them to plot some points. 
Then I draw a regression line with all those points. No problem up here.

The problem is that I want to have a semi-log scale, so I set the y-axes on Log.
I know that the regression line is not going to be straight because of the log. But then I also give the line some Log data. (without the log everything works)
The code at that point :

```
require(stats)
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(2,2.5,2.8,3.1,3.2,3.6,4.2,4.6,4.8,5,5.5,6.2,6.9,8)
y <- c(1.8,2.3,2.6,2.9,3.5,3.9,4.2,4.5,4.6,5,5.1,5.3,6.2,7.3)

ggplot(data=NULL , aes(x=x, y=log(y))) + 
    coord_trans(y = "log10")+ 
    geom_point(size=2.5, shape=20) + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, formula= log(y)~x , se=FALSE, colour="black")
```

This code shows this graph : 
[image: My plot (clic)]

The problem is that I want the line to "follow" the path of the points (not to be at the bottom) and to be straight.

> It worked with another method but now with ggplot, it doesn't work.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

*Edited after clarification from the question author*

It sounds like you want `scale_y_log10()` instead of `coord_trans(y = "log10")`. Per the documentation of `coord_trans`:

> The difference between transforming the scales and transforming the
>   coordinate system is that scale transformation occurs BEFORE
>   statistics, and coordinate transformation afterwards. **Coordinate
>   transformation also changes the shape of geoms**

To keep a straight line use `scale_y_log10()` like so:

```
require(stats)
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,9,11,11,11,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,18,18,18)
y <- c(1,2,4,3,3,2,5,4,6,3,7,7,6,7,8,4,5,4,9,9,13,14,15,15,15,16,17,19,19,20)

ggplot(data=NULL , aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(size=2.5, shape=20)  + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, formula= y~x, se=FALSE, colour="black") +
    scale_y_log10()
```

And get
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem of the non-straight line is still here. Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: Well, it's curved because the axis is log transformed as well. Even though the data is log transformed, a linear regression is going to have a linear slope which will appear curved on a semi-log scale like this.

Comment: Yes well I guess my problem is unsolvable, even tho it worked with other functions, weird. thanks btw

Comment: Can you show what you did with the other functions to give an idea of the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I previously used this code : (I had to change for some aesthetic reasons)

```
require(stats)
x <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,9,11,11,11,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,18,18,18)
y <- c(1,2,4,3,3,2,5,4,6,3,7,7,6,7,8,4,5,4,9,9,13,14,15,15,15,16,17,19,19,20)

plot(x,y, log="y", col="blue", pch=20,xlim=c(min(x), max(x)+2), ylim=c(min(y), max(y)+2))
mod1 <-lm(log10(y) ~ x) 
abline(mod1, lwd=1, col="blue")
```

It gave me this (The scale was semi-log with a straight line):
[image]